# Positions of a string in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

Sorry for the bad title..Didn't know how to describe this, feel free to change it to be more specific.

I have a list in this form:

```
list = {"a(0)", "a(1)", "a(2)"}
```

Now I want the positions of all a* in the list. At first I thought this is easily done with the Position-function, but then I had some difficulties:

```
Position[list, "a"]
```

Thought this would work, but somehow I'm missing something. So..how to implement the * to give me all a's regardless of the following characters?

Comment: StringPosition[list, "a"]？

Comment: omg..of course! I forgot to transform my list into a string :)..

Comment: No need to transform anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use `Position` :)...

```
Position[list, s_String?(! StringFreeQ[#, "a"] &)]
```

> ```
> {{1}, {2}, {3}}
> ```

Comment: This is nice and I get the correct results. But there is a warning message which I don't understand: StringFreeQ::strse: "String or list of strings expected at position 1 in \!\(StringFreeQ[List, \"a\"]\). "

Comment: Try  `Position[list, s_String?(! StringFreeQ[#, "a"] &)]`.

Comment: works fine now! Can you explain why what the problem was maybe? Want to understand it :)

Comment: @holistic `Position` is scanning everything, `Heads` too, that's why we had to constrain the pattern. You could also do `Position[list, s_?(! StringFreeQ[#, "a"] &), Heads->False]` but the method with `String` is more safe in case of nonstrigs in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {"a(0)", "a(1)", "a(2)", "b(42)"}
```

You can get the elements that match like so:

```
els = Select[list, StringMatchQ[#, "a" ~~ ___] &]

(*
{"a(0)", "a(1)", "a(2)"}
*)
```

If you want their positions, you can map `Position` over this list:

```
Position[list, #] & /@ els

(*
{{{1}}, {{2}}, {{3}}}
*)
```